# intrinsic way to create a map so that each element of a vector can be passed, along with a scalar

Tags: lisp

I put together a function that performs a modified sieve of Eratosthenes that does work.  I realize that this is an example of where iteration would provide a huge speed advantage over mapping, but that was not the point of writing this way.

Here is the code

```
(defun sieve (n)
  (let ((primes (list)))
    (do ((i 2 (1+ i)))
        ((> i n))
      (if (not
           (find 0 (mapcar (lambda (x) (mod i x)) primes)))
          (setf primes (append primes (list i)))))
    primes))

(print (sieve 100000))
```

This runs in about 3 seconds in sbcl and prints all the primes less than 100k.  clisp takes about 8 seconds.

I wanted to build a vector of primes, and then provide a map function to divide a scalar (which happens to be next number to be tested as to whether it is prime) by the vector of known primes to return a new vector of the modulo values.  If any of the modulo values are zero, it is not prime.

If it is prime, I wanted to add that prime to the vector of primes and continue.  I had no trouble using make-array to create an :adjustable collection, but then I ran into a road block:

I could not figure out how to create a map that would allow me to act on a scalar by a vector and return a vector.  To work around this, I re-wrote the code to use lists and to use mapcar.

As I said, it works, but I believe the setf to store the list each time is highly inefficient.  (The fact that I am doing a lot of unnecessary division because I am using mapping functions notwithstanding).

Every mapping function for arrays I could find required that the inputs be vectors and the output a single vector the size of the smallest input vector.

So, the real question is, is there an intrinsic way to create a map so that each element of a vector can be passed, along with a scalar to a function that produces an output vector the size of the input vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is map-vec

```
— Function: map-vec f v
```

Map the Lisp function f over the Calc vector v.

For example,

```
(map-vec 'math-floor v)
```

returns a vector of the floored components of vector v

Answer (score 1):

```
CL-USER 50 > (map 'vector #'1+ #(1 2 3 4))
#(2 3 4 5)

CL-USER 51 > (map 'vector
                  (lambda (e)
                    (* e 1234))
                  #(1 2 3 4))
#(1234 2468 3702 4936)
```